# compass image rotate as here map

Tags: ios, here-api

Map Orientation works as this code. But compass image is not rotate as per map rotate. Please help how to make compass as here map

```
 - (void)mapView:(NMAMapView *)mapView didReceiveRotation:(float)rotation atLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
[self.mapView setOrientation:180 withAnimation:NMAMapAnimationLinear];
 _comPassImg.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);//not working smoothly
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `NMAMapView::NMAMapEvent::NMAMapEventOrientationChanged` instead, e.g.:

```
[mapView respondToEvents:NMAMapEventOrientationChanged withBlock:^BOOL (NMAMapEvent event, NMAMapView *mapView, id eventData) {
    _comPassImg.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(mapView.orientation);
    return YES;
}];
```

You can also try `NMAOrientableMapMarker` to see if that works for you.

Comment: its working perfectly but the speed of a compass is very fast. Please help.

Comment: You can use a `UIViewAnimation` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585043/275524 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585043/275524