# UIImageView animation when UISwipeGestureRecogniser is occured in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

My Scenario is, i have collection of images in an array. dynamically creating UIImageView in a UIScrollView. code is shown below.

```
- (void)createImage
{
    UIImageView *imgFashion;

    CGFloat newHeight = 0.0;
    int xPos = 10;
    int yPosL = 10;
    int yPosR = 10;

    btnScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 83, 320, 485)];

    for (int i=0; i<[buttonImageArr count];i++)
    {

        UIImage *img = [buttonImageArr objectAtIndex:i];
        originalImageWidth = img.size.width;
        originalImageHeight = img.size.height;

        newHeight = originalImageHeight * (150/originalImageWidth);
        if (xPos == 10)
        {

            imgFashion=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPosL, 150, newHeight)];
            xPos = 160;
            yPosL = yPosL + newHeight;

        }
        else
        {
            imgFashion=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPosR, 150, newHeight)];
            imgFashion.tag=i;
            xPos = 10;
            yPosR +=newHeight;
        }
        imgFashion.tag=i;
        imgFashion.image = [buttonImageArr objectAtIndex:i];
        imgFashion.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [btnScroller addSubview:imgFashion];
        imgFashion.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
        imgFashion.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *profile_SwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes_profile:)];

        profile_SwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        profile_SwipeGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        profile_SwipeGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        [imgFashion addGestureRecognizer:profile_SwipeGestureRecognizer];
        btnScroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
    }

    btnScroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(xPos, yPosR+newHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:btnScroller];

}
```

Now i will swipe top of any images, i want to remove that image from view. i write the code for this functionality.

```
- (void)handleSwipes_profile:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)paramSender
{
    if (paramSender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        [paramSender.view removeFromSuperview];
        selectedBtn = paramSender.view.tag;
        [buttonImageArr removeObjectAtIndex:selectedBtn];
        [btnScroller removeFromSuperview];
        btnScroller = nil;
        [self createImage];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

My Question is, i want to rotate the image before remove from view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the animation methods of UIView with options like UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear and repeat count like below

```
- (void)handleSwipes_profile:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)paramSender
{
    if (paramSender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2f
                              delay: 0.0f
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations: ^{
                             [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
                             paramSender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(UserNameField.transform, M_PI );
                         }
                         completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"finished");
                             if (finished) {
                                 [paramSender.view removeFromSuperview];
                                 selectedBtn = paramSender.view.tag;
                                 [buttonImageArr removeObjectAtIndex:selectedBtn];
                                 [btnScroller removeFromSuperview];
                                 btnScroller = nil;
                                 [self createImage];
                                 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

                             }
                         }];
    }


}
```

If you need more options have a look at this question [UIView Infinite 360 degree rotation animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844925/uiview-infinite-360-degree-rotation-animation)

Comment: Hi Vignesh, Thanks for your answer. its working very nice. what i expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ´- animationWithDuration´ method like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    // perform your rotation here
    [_yourImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180)];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [paramSender.view removeFromSuperview];
    selectedBtn = paramSender.view.tag;
    [buttonImageArr removeObjectAtIndex:selectedBtn];
    [btnScroller removeFromSuperview];
    btnScroller = nil;
    [self createImage];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}];
```