# Image rotation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uianimation

I want to rotate an image by 360 degree delay for 2 or 3 seconds again rotate it by 360 degree and the process should continue on. Any possible suggestions for the same ? Actually tried Cgaffinetransfom but its not working for 360 degree .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844925/uiview-infinite-360-degree-rotation-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate your image like this:

```
[YourImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10*(M_PI/360))];
```

Now to perform it continuous you need to set the timer like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(doRotateImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Rotate function:

```
-(void)doRotateImage{
    [YourImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10*(M_PI/360))];
}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this method:

```
- (void)rotateImageView{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    [yourImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(yourImageView.transform, M_PI_2)];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
        [self rotateImageView];
    }
}];
}
```