# IOS/Objective-C: 360 Image Rotation Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm trying to rotate an image repeatedly (360) with an interval. I found this answer([Image rotation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440829/image-rotation-in-ios)), appears to be ok, but it's not working for me. When I load the VC I can see slight movement, but that's it. Any ideas? The code I'm using:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.compass setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10*(M_PI/360))];


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)rotation{
    [self.compass setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10*(M_PI/360))];

}
```

EDIT:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.compass setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10*(M_PI/360))];


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)rotation{
    [self.compass setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10*(M_PI/360))];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.compass.transform, 10*(M_PI/360));
    [self.compass setTransform:transform];
}
```

Comment: You need to use the [UIView animateWithDuration] method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animate the rotation as follow:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        compas.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    }];
```

Comment: well thanks for the answers, but the rotation isnt continuous: 
the method rotation: -(void)rotation{
    [self.compass setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10*(M_PI/360))];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.compass.transform, 180*(M_PI/360));
    [self.compass setTransform:transform];
}
Like this the compass just moves 180 dgs and stays that way...

Comment: ok, i misunderstand because of `repeats:YES`, i updated my answer

Comment: No, its the same, Constantin, I'll Edit so you can see the present code

Answer (score 0):

Your rotation is happening but it's just a very small rotation: 10*pi/360 radians is equal to 5 degrees. Pi radians is equal to 180 degrees so if you want to turn it 360 degrees rotate `2 * M_PI`.

Note however that you're currently not animating the movement and when you're just rotating a view without animation it will look exactly the same as when it's transform was still CGAffineTransformIdentity. To animate the transition, take a look at UIView animations: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the previous rotation in as well, otherwise you're rotating to the same angle over and over:

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(NewAngle + 10*(M_PI/360))
```