# Rotate image more than 180 degrees

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uianimation

I'm using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to transform and rotate an arrow in a meter.

[Picture of arrow that animates inside gage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhOjh.jpg)

The problem I am facing is that when I rotate more then 180 degrees the arrow rotates counter clockwise.

My goal is to rotate the arrow clockwise in the range of 1 to 280 degrees.

Example of the function that rotates the arrow:

```
func rotateNeedel(value: Int){
    var value = 220 //for testing purpose
    let degrees:CGFloat = CGFloat(value)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
        self.ImgMaalerArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((degrees * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    })}
```

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844925/uiview-infinite-360-degree-rotation-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CABasicAnimation` to rotate the view Clock-Wise

```
func rotateNeedel(value: Double, duration: Double){

    let fullRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    fullRotation.fromValue = Double(0)
    fullRotation.toValue = Double((value * M_PI)/180)
    fullRotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    fullRotation.duration = duration
    fullRotation.removedOnCompletion = false

    // add animation to your view
    self.ImgMaalerArrow.layer.addAnimation(fullRotation, forKey: "rotateViewAnimation")
}
```

Comment: Amazing! :D Thanks a lot