# Rotate UIView 360° forever

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I am trying to make this UIView rotate forever:

```
let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse.union(UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {            
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(2 * M_PI))
}, completion: { _ in })
```

Currently it does nothing because the rotation angle is the same position is it on right now. When I try something like M_PI it works and goes back and forth like it should, however it only does it halfway.

I am wondering how I can continue this rotation forever in a full 360 degree motion.

I tried this:
[UIView Infinite 360 degree rotation animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844925/uiview-infinite-360-degree-rotation-animation)
which has the same issue I do, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work since Obj-C -> Swift has many changes. Would rather use UIView.animate other than CAAnimation, but not sure if that is the only other way.

Comment: "Would rather use UIView.animate other than CAAnimation" Then you have not understood the linked answers, which show clearly why that's impossible. You _must_ use CABasicAnimation to do this reliably.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you, I will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CABasicAnimation, not view animation, and rotate additively, not to an absolute value. It will also help if you rotate 180 degrees additively forever as this is easier to express.