# Touch the image view and move in a circle on fix position

Tags: ios

[image]There is a clock image that has a needle for hour and a minute needle and I want to move that needle with hand in a circle. I am new in iOS development so please help me.

Comment: Use SwipeGestureRecognizer and play with Coordinations

Comment: What have you tried so far Shubham?  Do you have any images to show us or code?

Comment: yes I upload the image see below the question

Comment: @shubham.kaushik can you please check this ? I think this is perfect for your project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844925/uiview-infinite-360-degree-rotation-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my solution...
Use the viewNeedle and rotate it around a new pivot point. I've used an estension taken elsewhere here on StackOverflow.
Add the needle view on the clock view (made in the storyboard in my example).
Add a pan gesture to the view, calculate the angle (given in radiants) between the touch point and the centre of the clock view.
Then simply rotate the needle view.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewClock: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewNeedle: UIView!

    var panGestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(sender:)))
        viewNeedle.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        viewNeedle.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer!)
        viewNeedle.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1))
    }

    @objc func didPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: view)
        let center = viewClock.center
        let deltaY = location.y - center.y
        let deltaX = location.x - center.x
        let angle = Double(atan2(deltaY, deltaX)) + Double.pi/2
        viewNeedle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))
    }
}

 extension UIView {
     func setAnchorPoint(_ point: CGPoint) {
        var newPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * point.x, y: bounds.size.height * point.y)
        var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * layer.anchorPoint.x, y: bounds.size.height * layer.anchorPoint.y);

        newPoint = newPoint.applying(transform)
        oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(transform)

        var position = layer.position

        position.x -= oldPoint.x
        position.x += newPoint.x

        position.y -= oldPoint.y
        position.y += newPoint.y

        layer.position = position
        layer.anchorPoint = point
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @DungeonDev that's code working.. but set the y = 0.5 instead of 1. all code properly working..thankx

Comment: You are welcome. the 0.5 vs 1.0 depends on the needle asset ;)

Comment: hey @DungeonDev I have a question in that image one hour niddle is more so how I can rotate that niddle also problem is that the hour niddle layer below the minute middle layer..