# Rotate a view 360 degrees infinitely

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to rotate a view 360 degrees infinitely. But my view is not rotating:

```
func rotateImageView() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
            self.vinylView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi * 2)
        })
        
    }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIView Infinite 360 degree rotation animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844925/uiview-infinite-360-degree-rotation-animation)

Comment: UIView.animate will "look" at the final form of your image / view to determine how to animate it, so when you transform the image by .pi * 2, UIView.animate found no different hence seems do nothing. You could try separating the animation into few part and call them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute pi * with /, delete repeat, add completion and recall the function like this:

```
private func rotateImageView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.vinylView.transform = self.vinylView.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
    }) { (finished) in
        if finished {
            self.rotateImageView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using CABasicAnimation**

```swift
// Rotate vinvlView
vinylView.layer.add(CABasicAnimation.rotation, forKey: nil)

extension CABasicAnimation {
    static let rotation : CABasicAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity // Rotate a view 360 degrees infinitely
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
        animation.duration = 3.0
        return animation
    }()
}
```